# Video signal is available for usb type c on model hp pavilion ck000nq?

Tags: displayport, usb-c

I want to connect a monitor with 144hz on my laptop. Currently if I connect it only through hdmi I get 60hz. I tried to connect it through a USB C to Display Port adapter but I am not sure that my model supports Video through USB C. Can someone please help me to connect the monitor to the laptop to get 144hz? Is my USB C on my model HP Pavilion CK000NQ available for video signal?

Answer (score 0):

1. USB-C has NOTHING TO DO with your display.  It isn't a matter if your model supports it or not.
2. USB-C is a connector size.. not a specification of speed or capability; however, newer USB specifications are ONLY *currently* supported through the USB-C connector (like USB4) AND there are indeed USB-C cables that only support USB 2.0 speeds.

USB3 (and up..) support a fast enough transfer rate to allow a decent video signal to be sent over the USB bus and you will never get optimal "display port" speeds through this interface.

***"I am not sure that my model supports Video through USB C"*** -- YES, it does.  It has very little to do with your model.  Even much slower USB 2.0 could do this (even if the frame rates sucked).  I myself have used several USB to HDMI adapters but never a DisplayPort one.. (yet)

- I have found that all adapters are not created equal.  Some have worked well for me and some have not.
- I doubt VERY SERIOUSLY that you are going to pull ***144hz*** through an adapter like this unless by USB-C, you MEAN Thunderbolt 3.

Here are some articles that might help you understand:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C

https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/hdmi-vs-displayport-which-should-i-use-for-my-pc-monitor